# how to pass a value to another component in react

Tags: reactjs

SearchDomain.jsx

```
const SearchDomain = () => {
  let [searchValue , setsearchValue] = useState('')

  let SearchDomain = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
    }
  return (
     <>
            <div">
            <input
            type="search"
            placeholder="Search"
            aria-label="Search"
            aria-describedby="button-addon1"
            value={searchValue}
            onChange={(e)=>{setsearchValue(e.target.value)}}
            />

            <button
            type="button"
            id="button-addon1"
            data-te-ripple-init
            data-te-ripple-color="light"
            onClick={SearchDomain}>
            </button>
        </div> 
     </>
```

here is an input field, then clicking the button input field data store in 'searchValue'. and how to pass the searchValue to another component.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values between components using the props concept. I will share the code for you.

```
    import NewComponent from '../your path'

    const SearchDomain = () => {
      let [searchValue , setsearchValue] = useState('')
    
      let SearchDomain = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            
        }
      return (
         <>
                <div">
                <input
                type="search"
                placeholder="Search"
                aria-label="Search"
                aria-describedby="button-addon1"
                value={searchValue}
                onChange={(e)=>{setsearchValue(e.target.value)}}
                />
    
                <button
                type="button"
                id="button-addon1"
                data-te-ripple-init
                data-te-ripple-color="light"
                onClick={SearchDomain}>
                </button>
            </div> 


          <NewComponent value={searchValue } />
         </>
```

NewComponent.js

```
function NewComponent(props){
return(

<p>{props.value}</p> //here you cann access the value passed through the parent component

)
}
```

Comment: is't possible to use export method?

Comment: yes i have shared the updated code you can walkthrough it